# three.js load glb warning 'format' is not a property of this material

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

three.js is throwing `three.module.js:7950 THREE.MeshStandardMaterial: 'format' is not a property of this material.` when I load a .glb I made in blender.
Everything else works as expected. What dose this error mean? could it be that some property of my material I set in blender is not supported by threejs?

```
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load( '/myguy.glb', function ( gltf ) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    const myguyMesh = gltf.scene.children.find((child) => child.name === "Human_Mesh");

  }, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
  } );
```

i found this https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material

```
.format : Number
When this property is set to THREE.RGBFormat, the material is considered to be opaque and alpha values are ignored. Default is THREE.RGBAFormat.
```

but I don't really know where to go from here.

edit: i sort of know where to go from here.
there is some irrelevant(ish) glb property of my materials that is not accepted by three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mismatch between GLTFLoader version and three, I had a old three.js version, after updating it stopped

Comment: Had same issue just now, downloading the whole github and local linking of `three.min.js` and `GLTFLoader.js` from downloaded source worked, no CDN solutions worked when I wanted GLTFLoader

Answer (score 2):

I actually had the same problem as you! The first problem I can think of for it is that you had a texture for the object, and the code is trying to access it but can't get it, perhaps since it is in a different folder, etc. Another possibility is that the code is trying to access the texture through files that changed when exported. Good luck! -Codeitfast

Comment: deleted my materials in blender and the warning is gone now, but no colour :(, I read somewhere that three wont take certain properties like glb-specular or something but i cant find it now , thanks for the direction